# Cannot import package that I just installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, package

I created a virtual environment, installed pandas, and tried to import it:

```
$ pip install pandas ...
...
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas...
$ find $VIRTUAL_ENV -name pandas
/home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas
$ python -c 'import pandas'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
$ wh python 
python is /home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python
$ wh pip
pip is /home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/pip
```

One weirdness I noticed is:

```
$ ls /home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib*/python3.6/site-packages/
/home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/:
total 0

/home/sds/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/:
total 0
```

what am I doing wrong?

The "workaround" is:

```
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/myenv
for d in lib lib64; do
  cd $d/python3.6
  rmdir -v site-packages && mv -v dist-packages site-packages
  cd ../..
done
```

obviously, something is wrong...

PS. virtualenv setup:

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
pip3 install --user --upgrade virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv -p python3 myenv
```

Comment: How are you creating the virtualenv to begin with and what version of virtualenv are you using?

Comment: @TomDalton: see PS edit

Answer (score 0):

I just can guess which system you are using. I figured out that on mac I have to use `pip3 install ...` for packages I want to use with python 3.6.*.

Comment: I have colleagues who have had issues on Macs when using the 'system' python[3.6], some of which are resolved by using homebrew.